# What is the best way to transition from one scene to another completely different scene when writing a story?

Tags: style

To put it into perspective, separating a scene that involves two completely different characters and two completely different settings.

Comment: I was simply going to say: start a new chapter.  Sometimes it really is that easy.  But Raddevus gave some great ideas which may also work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Transitions can be done properly in a number of ways.  However, the first thing you need to do is:

**Decide the Relationship Between Scenes**

1. Are the two scenes at the same location and time except the second
   scene is from another character's viewpoint?
2. Are the two scenes following entirely different characters?
3. Are the two scenes following the same ViewPoint character, except at
   a new location / time?
4. Are the scenes actually just short character / plot vignettes?

A Few Scene Transitions

- If you are separating scenes only slightly by jumping to another
  viewpoint character you can do something as simple as make a break
  which includes a break symbol (series of asterisks) and a couple of
  white-space lines and then start with the other scene.
- If you are changing location and time you may want a chapter
  transition.  Just start writing the next chapter (scene).

**Transitions In Time With Same Character**

If you're just trying to say the same viewpoint character is at one place and then another later you can keep it simple.

Let's say viewpoint character was at a friends house and you want to show him at home.

> Later, Charlie unlocked his door and stumbled into his dark apartment.

**Transition To Another Viewpoint Character**

> Jane couldn't believe Charlie stormed out like that.  He just walked out
>   in the middle of the conversation.

**Transition Between Vignettes**

> "What're you talking about, Gwen," Charlie asked.  "Are you crazy or
>   something?" He grabbed the doorknob and ripped the door open, stepped
>   thru and slammed it behind him.
>
> ++++++++++
>
> Jane blinked at the sound of the door slamming.  "He's a bit dramatic,
>   right," Jane asked.   Gwen smiled and shrugged her shoulders.

Readers are smart and if you simply make your writing clear they will figure out you've transitioned from one place and time to another, which affords many opportunities for handling transitions.